# Retrieving the latest record for each unique entry in another column

Tags: unique, multiple-columns

This seems so simple but for the life of me cannot figure this out.  I have a table EERate with 3 columns and data similar to this.

```
EmployeeNo RateAmt RaiseDate

C100 | 10.00 | 1/1/2013
C100 | 11.00 | 6/1/2013
C100 | 10.50 | 8/1/2013
C200 | 15.00 | 6/1/2013
C200 | 16.00 | 8/1/2013
```

I need a select statement that will return the latest data for each employee.

`Select EmployeeNo, Max(RaiseDate), RateAmt from EErates group by employeeNo`
fails because rateamt is not an aggregate function.

`Select EmployeeNo, Max(RaiseDate), max(RateAmt) from EErates group by employeeNo`
retrieves the wrong data.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please revise your question with more details as to what you're looking for. How exactly do you want the results of your query to look and why is the output from your current query wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmployeeNo, RateAmt, RaiseDate FROM EErates o
WHERE RateAmt = (SELECT TOP 1 RateAmt FROM EErates i1 WHERE i1.EmployeeNo = o.EmployeeNo ORDER BY RaiseDate DESC)
AND RaiseDate = (SELECT TOP 1 RaiseDate FROM EErates i2 WHERE i2.EmployeeNo = o.EmployeeNo ORDER BY RaiseDate DESC)
```